# Laravel 5.1: with() helper is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `with()` helper to pass some error messages to views. My code for this is

```
 redirect('somewhere')->with('message', 'show some message')
```

Then in the targeted view to catch the message I have this:

```
@if(count($errors)>0)
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <ul >
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

But no message is delivered to the view. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 redirect('somewhere')->withErrors(['message', 'show some message'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot M0rtiis!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link [Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects)

In targeted view you can handle message like this

```
@if (session('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```